# Use of IN / NOT IN in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

For some reason, these two SQL statements not equivalent. Can anybody help in understanding why?

```
SELECT N, IF(P IS NULL, 'Root', IF(N NOT IN (SELECT P FROM BST), 'Leaf', 'Inner'))
FROM BST
ORDER BY N;

SELECT N, IF(P IS NULL, 'Root', IF(N IN (SELECT P FROM BST), 'Inner', 'Leaf'))
FROM BST
ORDER BY N;
```

P.S. - This is the Binary Search Tree problem on HackerRank. 
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/binary-search-tree-1

Comment: NOT IN (null) has fooled many users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jarlh's comment above is correct, i.e. nothing compares TRUE with NULL except the test IFNULL or 'is null'.  So if the query:

```
(SELECT P FROM BST)
```

returns a single NULL value, the two SQL statements will return different results.  This can easily be demonstrated with the following two SQL statements:

```
select if (1 in (select null), 'a', 'b') => 'b'

select if (1 not in (select null), 'b', 'a') => 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  `NOT IN` has strange semantics when the underlying table has `NULL` values.  In this case, the clause filters out all rows.

For this reason, I think `NOT EXISTS` is a better alternative:

```
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM BST WHERE BST.P = BST.N)
```

You can also fix this by adding `WHERE P IS NOT NULL` to the two subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

Statement `X IN (A,B)` translates to `X=A OR X=B`. When you use OR only one of the statements needs to be TRUE for whole expression to be TRUE. If either A or B is NULL that part of comparison will equal to NULL but the other part can still get you the result.

Let's say B is null, and A is in fact equal to X. That would be TRUE OR NULL, which is TRUE.

Statement `X NOT (A,B)` translates to `X<>A AND X<>B`. When using AND all statements need to be TRUE for the whole result to be TRUE. And if one of the sides is NULL whole statement will resolve to NULL, which is not TRUE.

If B is null, and X is not A, you would get TRUE OR NULL, and get NULL at the end.